# How do I grep the contents of files returned by grep?

Tags: bash, grep

When I look for log files with an error message using `grep error *log`, it returns a list of logfiles

```
$grep error *log

Binary file out0080-2011.01.07-12.38.log matches
Binary file out0081-2011.01.07-12.38.log matches
Binary file out0082-2011.01.07-12.38.log matches
Binary file out0083-2011.01.07-12.38.log matches
```

However, these are text, not binary files.

I am not sure why these are considered binary, the first few lines contain the following non-error messages:

```
out0134
-catch_rsh /opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-0-17/active_jobs/327708.1/pe_hostfile
compute-0-17
```

I would like to grep the **contents of** the returned files for an error message and return the names of the files with the message.

How can I grep the contents of the returned files, rather than this list of returned files, as happens with `grep error *log | grep foo`?

Comment: "Incidentally, ..." As SeigeX points out, that's not incidental at all. grep is, in fact, grepping those files and finding at least one match. It's just not printing the match(es) because it thinks the files are binary.

Comment: @jefromi, I updated my question to reflect your point, but I think that this has detracted from my ultimate goal which is to return the names of the files that contain `foo`

Comment: I'm confused about your ultimate goal, then. Do you want files which contain both error and foo, possibly in completely different places, or are you looking for `error.*foo` (probably an error message containing foo)? In the latter case you don't need two patterns at all.

Comment: @Jefromi I am looking for the first case, files which contain both `error` and `foo`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the answer you might be looking for:

```
grep -l foo $(grep -l error *.log)
```

`-l` tells grep to print filenames only; that does the first grep, then substitutes the result into the next grep's command. Alternatively, if you like xargs:

```
grep -l error *.log | xargs grep -l foo
```

which does the same thing, using xargs to call the second grep with the first grep's results as arguments.

Comment: @Jefroni thanks.. for both the code and the explanation, works perfectly

Comment: what if we have a space in the filename

Answer (score 6):

> -a, --text
>           Process  a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to
>           the --binary-files=text option.

`grep -a "some error message" *.log`

Btw, here is how grep determines binary from text files

> If the first few bytes of a file
>   indicate that the file contains binary
>   data, assume that the file is of type
>   TYPE.  By default,  TYPE  is
>                 binary...

#### Update

If you want just a list of file names which contain the word **foo** within the line that also contains **error** then you can do one or the other of these:

`grep -la "error.*foo" *.log`  <-- assumes **foo** comes after **error**

Comment: @Siege, although the output says different, these are text, not binary files

Comment: @David whatever grep is using to determine binary vs text, your files are triggering.  Thus you force `grep` to treat them as text with the `-a` option.  If this doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: If I use `-B 400` to output 400 lines, `grep -a -B 400 "error" *.log | grep foo` gets me closer to what I want, except that `foo` occurs many times per file and I only want the list of files that contain `foo` at all, not all of the lines that contain foo.

Comment: @Siege here are the first few lines: `out0143`, 
`-catch_rsh /opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-0-17/active_jobs/327708.1/pe_hostfile`, `compute-0-17`

Comment: @SiegeX thanks. but what if foo comes before error? it seems trivial to switch `error.*foo` with `foo.*error` or `foo*error` but this does not seem to work.

Comment: @Siege yes... so I guess that is the trouble

Comment: @David yes, in that case Jefromi's answer is the correct way to do this. Guess he's better at guessing than I am =)

Answer (score 3):

I do this.

> $find . -type f -name *.log | fgrep -v
>   [anything unwanted] | xargs grep -i
>   [search inside files]

Answer (score 0):

A comment asked about how to only grep for foo in the files that match the error, you can:

```
for i in *log ; do
    grep -a error $i >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
        echo -e "File $i:\n\t"
        grep -a foo $i
    }
done
```

Comment: thanks for this. Actually, I only want the file names that contain foo, not all of the lines.