# How do I grep the contents of files returned by ls and grep?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

How do I grep on files returned from a ls and grep command

e.g.

```
# ls -alrth /app/splunk_export/*HSS* | grep 'Nov 24 11:*'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  63K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1000+1300-1100+1300_HSS01HAM_CGP.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  40K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1000+1300-1100+1300_HSS01HAM_USCDB.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 138K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1000+1300-1100+1300_HSS01HAM.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 167K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1000+1300-1100+1300_HSS01KPR_FE.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  71K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1000+1300-1100+1300_HSS01KPR_USCDB.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  63K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1000+1300-1100+1300_HSS01KPR.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1030+1300-1100+1300_HSS01HAM_CGP.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  75K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1030+1300-1100+1300_HSS01HAM.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  90K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1030+1300-1100+1300_HSS01KPR_FE.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  28K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1030+1300-1100+1300_HSS01KPR.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1045+1300-1100+1300_HSS01HAM.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 140K Nov 24 11:17 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1045+1300-1100+1300_HSS01KPR_FE.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15K Nov 24 11:34 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1100+1300-1115+1300_HSS01HAM.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 140K Nov 24 11:34 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1100+1300-1115+1300_HSS01KPR_FE.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Nov 24 11:34 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1100+1300-1130+1300_HSS01HAM_CGP.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  75K Nov 24 11:34 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1100+1300-1130+1300_HSS01HAM.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  91K Nov 24 11:34 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1100+1300-1130+1300_HSS01KPR_FE.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  28K Nov 24 11:34 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1100+1300-1130+1300_HSS01KPR.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15K Nov 24 11:34 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1115+1300-1130+1300_HSS01HAM.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 139K Nov 24 11:34 /app/splunk_export/A20171124.1115+1300-1130+1300_HSS01KPR_FE.csv
```

I would like to search the above files for the following string `1693701622`

I have tried using xargs, but need some guidance.

```
# ls -alrth /app/splunk_export/*HSS* | grep 'Nov 24 11:*' | xargs grep -l 1693701622
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

NOTE: possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650026/how-do-i-grep-the-contents-of-files-returned-by-grep) but I think mine is slightly different

Comment: `find . -type f -newermt 2017-11-24 ! -newermt 2017-11-25 -exec grep -l 1693701622 {} \;`

Comment: The concrete error is because you are passing `-rw-r--r--` as an argument to `grep` by way of `xargs` and of course, that's seen as an invalid option name.  `grep` has an `-e` flag to let you pass in a regular expression which starts with a dash but of course, in this case, you only actually want to pass in the actual file names.  The answer with Awk ends up being what you want anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You are not extracting the file name and the whole line (with the leading dashes) is being picked up by `xargs` and that's why the error.

Use `awk` to do the filtering.  That would work better than `grep` since it handles repeated spaces gracefully:

```
ls -alrth |  awk 'match($6$7$8, /Nov2411:.*/) { print $9 }' | xargs grep -l 1693701622
```

In general, it is not a good idea to parse the output of ls.  See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) post for why.

For your requirement, it might be better to use `find` to pick up the files based on their timestamp and then pass them to `xargs grep ...`.

See this related post:

- [Recursively find all files newer than a given time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964747/find-all-files-recursively-newer-than-given-time)